# Creating a Multi-Step questionnaire with HTML, JS, FLASK and MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, flask

i am trying to make a multi-step questionnaire where there are 3 steps. This questionnaire allows users to input their desired answers and will return company names that are in the selected category, features and integration needed. This data is stored in the MySQL database, i will attach a diagram of the schema.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VTCZ.png)

- Step 1 is category, uses radio button as only one can be selected.
- Step 2 is Features, uses checkbox as multiple items can be selected
- Step 3 is integration, uses radio button as only one can be selected.

The way i have tried to implement this is to include the user input value into the SQL select query and then use the results as the next step values. The issue i have is, as it is multi-step the second query does not run until the full questionnaire is submitted. Also i get the feeling this not the right way to do it as questions will not load if the database does not respond quickly.

Can i implement Javascript to do the multi-step logic and then run one query at the end? i am kind of lost on how to go about this.

Any help with be greatly appreciated.

App.py

```
@app.route('/home', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():

    firstInput = ''
    myresult2 = ''
    sqlFirst = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM categories;'
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstInput = request.form.get('cat_in')
        my_data = (firstInput,)
        

        fetchFetch = 'SELECT distinct features.features, categories.categories, mytable.cat_FK_KEY, categories.categoryID, mytable.Categories FROM mytable, features, nameFeatures, categories WHERE mytable.id = `nameFeatures`.`name_FK_ID`  and features.featureID = nameFeatures.feature_FK_ID and mytable.cat_FK_KEY = categories.categoryID and categories.categoryID = %s;'
        cursor.execute(fetchFetch, my_data)

        myresult2 = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.execute(sqlFirst)
    myresult = cursor.fetchall()

   


    return render_template('index.html', firstInput=firstInput, myresult=myresult, myresult2=myresult2)
```

index.html

```
<form id="regForm" action="" method="post">
  
  
  <div class="tab">Please pick a Category:
    {% for row in myresult %} 
    <input type="radio" id="{{row[0]}}" oninput="this.className = ''" name="cat_in" value="{{row[0]}}">
    <label for="{{row[0]}}">{{row[1]}}</label><br>

    {% endfor %} 

  </div>
  <div class="tab">Select the features:
    <p>{{firstInput}}</p>
    {% for row in myresult2 %} 
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{row[0]}}" oninput="this.className = ''" name="feature_in" value="{{row[0]}}">
    <label for="{{row[0]}}">{{row[0]}}</label><br>
    {% endfor %} 
  </div>
  
  <div class="tab">Which intergration:

  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    //document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").submit();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {

  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form...
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    // ... the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
  console.log(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  console.log(valid);
  return valid; // return the valid status
  
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}

</script>
```

Comment: Is this on a webpage ?  Do you have a server side language

Comment: I am using Python (Flask framework) for server side

Comment: The answer is yes you can.  But you are asking too much,  This site is not really about design of software, as much as problems in software.  With the scope so large, I dont think many are willing to invest the time required.  Break it down, ask about one step at a time.